# Finding the match percentage between 2 statement

Tags: go

I've the below 2 strings, that actually means the same:

```
GLOVES: LENGTH: 32 CM MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER FREE FLOW TEXT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF GLOVES, TYPE: CHEMICAL RESISTANT, SIZE: 7, MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER, STANDARD: BS EN 388/BS EN 374, FFT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF CHEMICALS SUCH AS ETHYLENE OXIDE IDEAL FOR LONG TERM HEAVY WORK IN CHEMICAL ENVIRONMENT MANUFACTURER REFERENCES: ORIGINAL_MNFR: POLYCO
```

And

```
Neoprene Rubber Chemical Resistant Gloves, Size: 7; Length: 32 cm; Standard: BS EN 388; Resistant to wide range of Chemicals such as Ethylene Oxide. Make: Polyco, Model: Duraprene III or Equivalent
```

I've more than 1000 sets like this, which is panic to do them manually, I tried to do them as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var str1 = "Neoprene Rubber Chemical Resistant Gloves, Size: 7; Length: 32 cm; Standard: BS EN 388; Resistant to wide range of Chemicals such as Ethylene Oxide. Make: Polyco, Model: Duraprene III or Equivalent"
    var str2 = "GLOVES: LENGTH: 32 CM MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER FREE FLOW TEXT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF GLOVES, TYPE: CHEMICAL RESISTANT, SIZE: 7, MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER, STANDARD: BS EN 388/BS EN 374, FFT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF CHEMICALS SUCH AS ETHYLENE OXIDE IDEAL FOR LONG TERM HEAVY WORK IN CHEMICAL ENVIRONMENT MANUFACTURER REFERENCES: ORIGINAL_MNFR: POLYCO"

    cnt := 0
    for _, i := range strings.Fields(str1) {
        for _, j := range strings.Fields(str2) {
            if strings.ToLower(i) == strings.ToLower(j) {
                cnt += 1
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("str1 is: %d length, and str2 is: %d length, they have; %d common words.", len(str1), len(str2), cnt)
}
```

But the match is very low, I got:

```sh
str1 is: 197 length, and str2 is: 358 length, they have; 29 common words.
```

I tried also using [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as:

```golang
// Levenshtein Distance in Golang
package main
import "fmt"
 
func levenshtein(str1, str2 []rune) int {
    s1len := len(str1)
    s2len := len(str2)
    column := make([]int, len(str1)+1)
 
    for y := 1; y <= s1len; y++ {
        column[y] = y
    }
    for x := 1; x <= s2len; x++ {
        column[0] = x
        lastkey := x - 1
        for y := 1; y <= s1len; y++ {
            oldkey := column[y]
            var incr int
            if str1[y-1] != str2[x-1] {
                incr = 1
            }
 
            column[y] = minimum(column[y]+1, column[y-1]+1, lastkey+incr)
            lastkey = oldkey
        }
    }
    return column[s1len]
}
 
func minimum(a, b, c int) int {
    if a < b {
        if a < c {
            return a
        }
    } else {
        if b < c {
            return b
        }
    }
    return c
}
 
func main(){
    var str1 = []rune("Neoprene Rubber Chemical Resistant Gloves, Size: 7; Length: 32 cm; Standard: BS EN 388; Resistant to wide range of Chemicals such as Ethylene Oxide. Make: Polyco, Model: Duraprene III or Equivalent")
    var str2 = []rune("GLOVES: LENGTH: 32 CM MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER FREE FLOW TEXT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF GLOVES, TYPE: CHEMICAL RESISTANT, SIZE: 7, MATERIAL: NEOPRENE RUBBER, STANDARD: BS EN 388/BS EN 374, FFT: RESISTANT TO WIDE RANGE OF CHEMICALS SUCH AS ETHYLENE OXIDE IDEAL FOR LONG TERM HEAVY WORK IN CHEMICAL ENVIRONMENT MANUFACTURER REFERENCES: ORIGINAL_MNFR: POLYCO")
    fmt.Println("Distance between str1 and str2:",levenshtein(str1,str2))
}
```

But the distance between them looks to be very long, I got:

```sh
Distance between str1 and str2: 304
```

Any idea how can i improve this?

Comment: Well, these two strings indeed do not look anything like each other.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev actually they are same description of the same product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may describe the same thing, but you're comparing them using algorithms with no understanding of that.

For example, [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is just a measure of the number of inserts, deletes, and substitutions it would take for one string to equal another. It will work just as well on "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy grey dog" as it will on "Dlkj adlkjll o824hs aldkj ladhfj adlbcvhiuywe". It has no understanding of vocabulary or grammar.

In contrast, no amount of string processing will recognize that "the bright red house stood before me" is describing the same thing as "to my front was a shining rosy dwelling".

You need to look for [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) algorithms or NLP. These are not simple to use and require some finesse. I'm no NLP expert, I'd suggest starting with some searches for [golang nlp](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=golang+nlp&ia=images) and go from there.